# Second vs. third person in future imperative for a general rule or maxim

Tags: grammar-choice, translation-check, english-to-latin-translation, conjugation

I am trying to translate "*plan [in order] to achieve*" into Latin.

Is it more appropriate to use second ("*meditator ut consequaris*") or third person ("*meditator ut consequatur*") in future imperative here?

If both are acceptable, which one sounds more natural for a general rule or maxim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the passive imperative suffers from similarity to the agent noun derived from the verb.
This usually happens in the first conjugation.
That is, the imperative *meditator* ("plan!") looks like the noun *meditator* ("planner"), and vowel lengths match as well.
My first reaction to this word is that it's a noun.
Therefore my starting point to choose a phrasing that makes this reading less likely or less harmful.

My immediate reading of *meditator ut consequatur* is "so that a planner would achieve".
The imperative reading might not occur to me at all unless there is a clear person being ordered.
For a motto it sounds weird to say "may he plan so that he achieves".
Who's he?
Therefore I don't quite like the third person option, although it is grammatically perfectly valid.

I think a motto with an order works better when aimed to the reader.
The second person motto *meditator ut consequaris* can still be misread as "so that you would achieve as a planner", but that is less likely than with the third person.
And that alternative reading isn't all that bad; giving two legitimate but different readings with essentially the same message is a nice play with words.

I prefer the second person option.
Just because the future imperative is ambiguous, I would consider changing it to the usual imperative: *meditare*.

If I may suggest an alternative wording using these words, I think a more natural choice is to use a gerund to express the means.
This makes the roles of the two verbs abundantly clear, and it sounds somehow more Latin to me in style:

> *Meditando consequeris.*
>   You will achieve by planning.

As to whether *meditari* and *consequi* are the best verbs for your purpose, I will have to point you to [an online Latin dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).
Whichever verbs you end up picking, my recommended structure is this last one with a gerund and a future tense.
Of course, the ablative gerund can be replaced with the ablative form of a noun if the means can be described well with a noun.
Bear in mind, though, that a gerund will make it more active.
To me *meditando* gives the impression that you actually have to plan yourself, whereas *consilio* just gives the circumstances and makes me think you are working on someone else's recommendation.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a comprehensive answer, Joonas!

Comment: Based on your description it looks like "*meditando*" better conveys my idea.
What do you think about semantic differences between "*consequeris*" and "*assequeris*"?

Comment: @Yuriy I'm glad to be able to help! Based on a quick dictionary look-up, I think *assequi* is a more suitable verb. You can always ask a new question about choosing the most appropriate translation for "achieve" in your context if you want more details on it. There is a long list of possible verbs: *consequi, assequi, perpetrare, perficere, pervincere, patrare, peragere...*

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to the community of [discord.gg/latin](https://discord.gg/latin) for help with translating this motto, and received three possible translations:

- "*meditator ut consequaris*",
- "*si vis consequi, meditare*", and
- "*consilio assequeris*".

Out of them the last one, "*consilio assequeris*" was recommended as the most appropriate.

Comment: I agree that the last one of these sounds most natural.

Comment: In my opinion, the last one also sounds quite natural but not so for a general rule or aphorism. E.g., cf. _Illud certissime tua ejus modi opera, diligentia, **consilio consequeris**, ut praeclarum hoc ad cetera adjunxeris tui erga regem ipsum obsequii testimonium et nostrum de tua virtute ac nobiscum judicium mirifice comprobaberis_ (https://books.google.es/books?pg=RA1-PA179&lpg=RA1-PA179&dq=consilio+consequeris&sig=ACfU3U1JDL4ARDPq6_h2eI3nCVr1sjQasg&id=VXM5DLZGihIC&hl=ca&ots=LV4ZgWTaAh#v=onepage&q=consilio%20consequeris&f=true )